# Switching of RS485 differential line. Two sources, one output

Tags: switches, rs485

I'm looking for a solution for my project.

I have two signal sources (primary source and secondary source) on the RS485 (A/B) differential line. When/if something goes wrong on the primary, then I switch over the button switches to the secondary source.

[image: Schematic showing unknown switch]

Which electric component could I use for switching the differential line (other than a relay)?

Comment: If you're going to do it manually use a double pole switch. Why not a relay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you don't wish to use a relay, you could possibly use a [CD4066](http://www.ti.com/product/CD4066B#), CMOS Quad Bilateral Switch ([datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cd4066b.pdf)):

[image: CD4066]

Although as suggested in Finbarr's [comment](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/433578/switching-of-rs485-differential-line-two-sources-one-output#comment1083380_433578), as you might want to use a double pole switch, you would want to use all four switches within the IC package.

See image below taken from [How to Build a 4066 Quad Bilateral Switch Circuit](http://www.learningaboutelectronics.com/Articles/4066-quad-bilateral-switch-circuit.php)

[image: Schematic]

Just modify the schematic to use the other two input and output pins as well as `Control C` and `Control D`

Comment: I don't want an electromagnetic relay. Analog switch is a super variant. Can I use this TS3A44159? Switching will be handled by the processor.

Comment: Could you edit and update your question to state why you don't want to use an electromagnetic relay? It might help in answering your question more precisely. WRT to the TS3A44159, I'm afraid that I'm not familiar with that device - although after a *brief* glance at the [datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ts3a44159.pdf) I can't see why not.

Answer (score 0):

The appropriate component here would be a relay – either in its electromagnetic form, or in the form of an analog switch.

There's dedicated bus switch ICs.

Comment: I don't want to use an electromagnetic relay. Can you recommend an analog switch? For this line?

Comment: @PetrTN: Seems worth looking at NX3L2467.  However in your diagram you have the switch in the wrong place -- it should be between the driver IC and the TVS protection, to avoid exposing the switch to ESD or coupled transients.